# Problem with Ruby, Rails, ZSH and RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zsh, rvm

When I go into my rails app folder and write:

```
which ruby
```

I get this:

```
/Users/gugguson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/ruby
```

When I write:

```
ruby -v
```

I get this:

```
ruby 1.9.3dev (2010-09-25 trunk 29341) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
```

Hovever when I run my app with:

```
rails s
```

I get an error indication it is using ruby 1.8.7 my app is using:

```
/Users/gugguson/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

zsh: abort      rails s
```

Do you know what can be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using system installed rails script, make sure that you use rails installed inside rvm and

```
head $(which rails)
```

starts with

```
#!/Users/gugguson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/ruby
```

Comment: I had `#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8`, that I replaced by `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`